# Is it worth running two While loops to determine initial starting point and number of iterations for a For loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script

I have a basic for loop that iterates through an array of values and executes a code if a certain value is found. The array is a column of true or false values obtained from a Google Sheet.

```
// array example: [[false], [false], [false], 
//                 [true], [false], [false],
//                 [false], [true], [false],
//                 [false], [false], [false]]

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 if (array[i][0] === true) {
  // execute code
 }
```

Is it worth (performance-wise) running two While loops to determine where the For loop should start and how many times it should iterate, or will it basically be the same?

```
var c = array.length - 1;
while (array[c][0] === false) {
 c--;
}

var d = 0;
while (array[d][0] === false) {
 d++;
}

var start_row = d+1;
var end_row = c+1;

for (i = start_row - 1; i < end_row; i++) {
 if (array[i][0] === true) {
  // execute code
 }
```

Both of these For loops seem to perform exactly the same, but I was hoping to get some input if one would be preferable over the other and why. In my head, the second case makes more sense since the For loop won't have to iterate unnecessarily from the very beginning of the array all the way through the end, but I may be completely wrong based on how this code is actually compiled and executed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there's any performance improvement(if not decrease).

Comment: Explicit comparison to `true` or `false` is *usually* a bad idea.

Comment: are you parsing through a values from a range? If so and if it's not a custom range use the `sheet.getDataRange()`this will avoid empty rows

Comment: These are values from a Google sheet range, but it's only a single column with the height determined by getLastRow() so I think that makes getValues(1,1,getLastRow(),1) faster than getDataRange.
@Pointy Thanks for the info, I didn't know that. I don't think I have another option though since these are "check boxes" on the Google sheet that are used to place orders and to determine if it's checked or unchecked I have to see if the value of that cell is true or false. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: you are missing I think a couple of things `getValues(1,1,getLastRow(),1)` is not valid and if you wan't to check wether it's true or false you do `values[rowIndex][columnIndex] == "TRUE"` or `== "FALSE"` with the quotes as you are evaluating string type values.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I'm using sheet.getRange(1,1,getLastRow(),1).getValues(). I'll make sure to change those TRUE and FALSE to strings. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like comparing to "TRUE" or "FALSE" requires using toString() and comparing to "true" or "false" (lowercase). Example: `array[i][0].toString() === "true"`. `array[i][0] === "true"` or  `array[i][0] === "TRUE"` does not work. At least not with Google's implementation of Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have specific needs to create additional loops - there is no much reason to do that. Anyway, these two `while` loops and the `for` loop will iterate the whole array together. The main goal in provided examples is to write less code I guess (you will not increase the speed of execution using provided code), so I recommend just to use a single `for` loop to decrease the size of your logic.

Answer (score 3):

The current implementation of Google Apps Script has some interesting quirks, one of which is that the aggregate array methods such as `map()`, `forEach()`, `some()` and `every()` perform better than a vanilla `for` loop. I know this flies in the face of conventional wisdom but there are some weird things at work under the hood.

Take a look at the following snippet:

```
var arr = [
        [false, false, false],
        [true, false, false],
        [false, true, false],
        [false, false, false]
    ];

arr.forEach(function(row){
    row.forEach(function(item){
        // do the things
    });
});
```

Believe it or not the above code is likely to execute faster than your `for` loop. One of the G+ GAS community's prominent members - Kanshi Tanaike - ran a number of benchmarks and made this discovery. You can check out his findings at the link below:

https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6

Hopefully Apps Script will behave in a more conventional manner when its eventually upgraded to use Chrome's V8 engine.

Answer (score 2):

No because the computational cost for the js interpreter for the `while` loops is not better respect to `for` approach, while the code gets less readable.

The approach of identifying index intervals of "compact" data works better with compiled languages (C/C++) where you (or the compiler) can exploit loop-unrolling techniques that requires to work in a "compact" array of data.